# Defining a range of values for ddply {plyr} to use when making combinations

Tags: r, plyr

I have camera trap data in a format with capture date, species, and number of individuals for each observation. For example:

```
> df
      Date Sp Num
1 1/1/2015  a   1
2 1/1/2015  a   1
3 1/1/2015  b   2
4 1/3/2015  a   4
```

I would like to sum the total number of each species recorded for a given day, but also expand the data set so that there is an entry for each date and species combination, with zero values for dates without an observation of a given species. I can do this with ddply {plyr} and the `.drop=FALSE` command.

```
> ddply(df, c("Date", "Sp"), function(df)sum(df$Num), .drop=FALSE)
      Date Sp V1
1 1/1/2015  a  2
2 1/1/2015  b  2
3 1/3/2015  a  4
4 1/3/2015  b  0
```

The problem is that there are some days in which no observations were made for any species (in the example above, this would be 1/2/2015). What I would like to return is something like this:

```
> df
      Date Sp Num
1 1/1/2015  a   2
2 1/1/2015  b   2
3 1/2/2015  a   0
4 1/2/2015  b   0
5 1/3/2015  a   4
6 1/3/2015  b   0
```

Is there a way to define a range of dates in a vector and ask ddply to use that instead of only the unique dates from the original dataframe?

I'm relatively new to R and SO, so I apologize in advance if this is too convoluted of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class.  Create a new dataset with the combination of sequence from minimum to maximum "Date" and the `unique` elements of "Sp".  Either we `merge` (from `base R`) or use `left_join` from `dplyr` after we get the `sum` of the 'Num' column grouped by 'Date' and 'Sp'.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df1 <- expand.grid(Date=seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date),
    by = "1 day"), Sp=unique(df$Sp), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Sp) %>% 
  summarise(Num = sum(Num)) %>%
  left_join(df1, .) %>%
  mutate(Num = replace(Num, is.na(Num), 0)) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(Date = format(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
#        Date Sp Num
#1 01/01/2015  a   2
#2 01/01/2015  b   2
#3 01/02/2015  a   0
#4 01/02/2015  b   0
#5 01/03/2015  a   4
#6 01/03/2015  b   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At some camera sites, I do not have observation on the first or last few days, so defining the date range as the min/max dates leaves out days on which I need to record zero observations.. I tried to define the date range as `expand.grid(Date=seq(min(2015-1-1), max(2015-1-20), by = "1 day")` but it does not seem to work. How can I define the date range?

Comment: @etis  By looking at `2015-1-1`, it is not of `Date` class. Convert to `Date` class and then get the `seq` of `min` and `max